# updated record is inserting into the history table not the old record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have two tables Test and TestHistory

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Status] [char](1) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_History](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Status] [char](1) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO TEST ([ID],[Name],[Status],[CreatedDate])values (1,'Mohan','A',GETDATE())
```

Created Trigger :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Test] 
     ON [dbo].[TEST]
     FOR UPDATE 
     AS

     Declare @ID INT;
     Declare @Name varchar(10);
     Declare @Status CHAR(2);
     Declare @CreatedDate DATETIME;


     Select @ID = I.ID from INSERTED I
     Select @Name = I.Name from INSERTED I
     Select @Status = I.Status from INSERTED I
     Select @CreatedDate = I.CreatedDate from INSERTED I


     INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_history]
           ([ID]
           ,[Name]
           ,[Status]
           ,[CreatedDate]
           )

          SELECT @ID,
                 @Name,
                 @Status,
                 GETDATE()

                    FROM INSERTED I

           WHERE @ID = [ID]
```

When I'm updating the record like

`Update  [TEST] SET Status = 'I'` then the old record with   `Status = 'A'` should inserted but the what ever i'm updating it has been inserting into Testhistory table not the old record
 where i'm doing wrong and how to insert old value

like if i updating `Status = 'I'`    and in history table `Status = 'A'` shoul be inserted

Comment: `Select @ID = I.ID from INSERTED I` This will not work when your insert/udate/delete sql effects more than one row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `INSERT` from `DELETED` not from `INSERTED`.

See examples here [Understanding SQL Server inserted and deleted tables for DML triggers](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/).

Comment: my bad it's the first time i'm writing triggers learned from my mistake

Comment: Happy to help. It is a well formed question and an easy answer. Sometimes SO is a simply about having another set of eyes on your code.

Answer (score 2):

Like Karl mentioned, you need to refer deleted table for old updated row information. Apart from that your existing code doesn't work when you update more than a single row. What you need is something like this.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Test] 
     ON [dbo].[TEST]
     FOR UPDATE 
     AS
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_history]
       (
       [ID],
       [Name],
       [Status],
       [CreatedDate]
       )
      SELECT ID,
             Name,
             Status,
             GETDATE()
      FROM deleted d
```